# How to change value of Locale.getDefault().getCountry() in my Android phone?

Tags: android, locale

I need to get the Locale.getDefault().getCountry() on my phone. But I am having trouble with a phone which is bought from different country. And now I'm in the United Arab Emirates but I am getting US on my Locale.getDefault().getCountry(). How can I change it on my phone? For testing purposes

Comment: Do you want to CHANGE the Locale, or just know where are you in the world?

Answer (score 0):

To Test your scenario.

In your device change language

**Settings -> Language and Keyboard Settings -> Select Language**

Then you can see the country as different.